# Ionic: Exactly the same code, different output?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

Hi Stackoverflow members,

I've set up a codepen here: [Link](http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/aOpKgL) 
Which works perfectly. However, when i try to implement this into my Ionic application it cannot receive the JSON data even though the code is almost exactly the same and i cannot understand why it's not working.

```
<body ng-controller="Controller">
<ion-view view-title="Announcements">
    <ion-content class="padding">

        <ion-refresher 
            pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
            on-refresh="doRefresh()">
        </ion-refresher>

        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="data in data">
                <div class="list card">
                    <div class="item item-divider">{{data.announcement_name}} - {{data.date}}</div>
                    <div class="item item-body">
                        <div>
                            {{data.message}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
</body>
```

And here's the controller:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
    .controller('Controller', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.doRefresh = function () {
            $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/3z1eg')
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.data = data;
                })
                .finally(function () {
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                });
        };
    }]);
```

I don't get any errors in console log when i run the code (which is annoying) so i have no idea what the problem is. Any help would be brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to white-list the address you're trying to access. [This plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) allows you to white-list addresses. For a catch-all solution you can add the following to your config.xml:

```
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Note however, this is not recommended. See the documentation for how to allow more specific URLs / protocols.

Comment: How do you add the Whitelist plugin?? What command is it? cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.Whitelist? something similar?   or cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist? Tried both but get errors

Comment: Try `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist` instead.